# Design custom entities for api.ai

Tags: bots, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am trying to develop the bot using api.ai and confused between street address and address. I have read the [documentation](https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-entities#section-geography) and got to know that it is for the US addresses only. Can I design it for myself for any city and what is the smart way to do so.

**Method I know**

1. creating the entities manually( add every places to the custom entity one by one).
2. One more method, user will write any address, bot will veritfy it with google maps if this vaild address than add it to the custom entity.( currently I don't know how will I do this but I think it can possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can use api.ai [APIs](https://docs.api.ai/docs/reference) to add custom entities. You can use python [geopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy/1.11.0) to verify and create/update your entities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read both the link that you have mentioned. But able to understand properly. for the first link(https://docs.api.ai/docs/reference) how do bot send the authorization token while interacting with the user. The second link (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy/1.11.0) how do I add geopy in api.ai. If you have any tutorial or any other link, please provide it.

Comment: What exactly is your bot doing? Is it adding a new address that is entered by the user in your chat prompt and adding it to your database?

Comment: No it is not adding the address in to the database. I want to add new addresses into the custom entities based on the some logic. ( so that when the next time anyone write the same address, user will not get same question, as bot keep on asking repeatedly when bots is not able to figure out what is it.)  And I don't want to add entities sys.any in to address . Hope it clear. @sarc360